# Button works fine on desktop but doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons one to increase a value in my database , the other to decrease. Both work perfectly on desktop but on mobile only the increase function works.

```js
$("body").delegate("#product", "click", function(event) {
  var pid = $(this).attr("pid");

  event.preventDefault();
  $(".overlay").show();
  $.ajax({
    url: "action.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      addToCart: 1,
      proId: pid,
    },
    success: function(data) {
      count_item();
      getCartItem();
      $('#product_msg').html(data);
      $('.overlay').hide();
    }
  })
})

$("body").delegate("#remove", "click", function(event) {
  var p_id = $(this).attr("p_id");

  event.preventDefault();
  $(".overlay").show();
  $.ajax({
    url: "action.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      removeCart: 1,
      proId: p_id,
    },
    success: function(data) {
      count_item();
      getCartItem();
      $('#product_msg').html(data);
      $('.overlay').hide();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<button class='btn btn-info' pid='$pro_id' id='product'>+</button>
<button class='btn btn-info' p_id='$pro_id' id='remove'>-</button>
```

Comment: `.delegate()` has been deprecated you should use `.on()`.

Comment: query  "update `cart` set qty=$var+1 where p_id=$prod and user_id = '$user_id'"; works fine but "update `cart` set qty=$remv-1 where p_id=$prod and user_id = '$user_id'"; works only on desktop

Comment: You shouldn't add custom attributes to elements. If you need application-specific attributes, use `data-XXX` attributes, which you can access in jQuery with `.data("XXX")`

Comment: What are `$var` and `$remv`? Why don't you just write `SET qty = qty + 1` and `SET qty = qty - 1`?

Comment: I don't see anything here that would work differently on desktop and mobile.

Comment: $remv=$row['qty'];

Comment: Does your webserver log show the decrement request being received from mobile?

Comment: I don't understand, why is it not working on mobile, if it works just fine on deskttop?

Comment: I can't tell you. You need to do proper debugging. Log the parameters you receive.